# Linux tool to specify baud rate for serial port

Tags: serial-port, serial-console

I have tried gtkterm and a couple of other tools. None of them seem to support a serial port baud rate which is higher than 115200. Could someone suggest some tools which will allow higher baud rates?

Comment: Have you tried `screen`? I haven't tried it with higher than that rates, but it might be worth trying (see http://superuser.com/questions/350061/gnu-screen-setting-the-default-baud-rate for an example)

Answer (score 0):

I have found screen and cu capable of these functions. Assuming that you are doing something like a USB-Serial adapter, the syntax would be:

```
cu -s 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://tio.github.io which support arbitrary bit rates on Linux. For example:

```
tio --baudrate 2000000 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If you need the commonly used 115200 8n1 you can simply do:

```
tio /dev/ttyUSB0
```